# Derivative of t per unit step - meaning of $t\delta (t)$

Tags: derivatives, education, mathematical-physics, dirac-delta

I derived the function ($u(t)$ is the unit step):

$$x(t)=t \space u(t)$$

$$dx/dt=1 \space u(t)+t \space \delta(t)$$

What is the graphical meaning of the second term?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $x(t)$ is a ramp and is not differentiable at $t=0$ (the left and right derivatives differ). The term $t\,\delta(t)$ accounts for that non-differentiability (the Heaviside step takes a finite value at $t=0$).

Graphically speaking, you can picture it as two infinitely close Dirac deltas with opposite signs (which implements a differentiation operator by convolution).

Comment: Hi @Yves Daoust, can you explain in detail what does "implements a differentiation operator by convolution" mean please?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi: check the integral definition of the $\delta$ distribution, as a convolution.

Comment: I don't know distributions. My professor introduced Dirac delta without the concept of distribution.

Comment: maybe $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{t\delta (t) dt}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\frac{x(t)\delta (t)}{u(t)} dt}=\frac{x(0)}{u(0)}=\frac{0u(0)}{u(0)}=0$? Thus the term hasn't area, so it does not exist on the graphic?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi: " it does not exist on the graphic": this doesn't make sense. You don't seem to have a true understanding of the $\delta$ "function".

Comment: can you suggest me any simple material to understand better Dirac delta please?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi: what is your course saying ?

Comment: I'm studying signals' theory and Dirac delta was introduced as ramp function with width 2e, 0 at t<-e, 1/2e at t>e. When e goes to 0, the above function goes to Dirac delta that has unit area, base=0, amplitude=infinity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some graphical meaning here, you should compare $\frac{dx}{dt}$ as a function that returns the slope of the graph of $x(t)$ with $u(t)$. The difference between these two graphs is exactly $t \delta(t)$. Try arguing graphically that $t \delta(t) = 0$, then convince yourself of this using the definition of $\delta(t)$ as a limit of proper functions.

Comment: Isn't $t\;\delta(t) =0\; \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score -1):

$\delta (t)$ is the Dirac delta function (well... distribution). This "function" assumes the value $\infty$ at zero and is zero everywhere else. The funny thing is

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \delta (t) \ dt = 1 $$

I suggest consulting the Wiki page. The Dirac delta is like a point pulse.

Comment: This should be tagged as a hint.

Comment: Hi @Sean Roberson, is it correct to say that $f(t)\delta (t-t_0)=\delta(t-t_0)$ and the area of delta is $|f(t_0)|$?

Comment: No. We have $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t) \delta (t-t_0) \ dt = f(t_0)$.

Comment: The Dirac Delta is NOT a function and assumes no values at any point.  It is a distribution that assigns to any suitable test function, the value of that function at $0$.

Comment: @MarkViola I am aware of this. I was giving the OP the "definition" I've seen in introductory ODE texts. Also note the quotes around "function" which is emphasizing some liberty (akin to air/bunny quotes).

Comment: @seanroberson I understand.  But why perpetuate the misinformation that is evidently so prevalent in the literature?  I prefer to provide a primer to clarify the essence of the Dirac Delta as a generalized function and show examples of regularizations thereof.